# Django Like function with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views, endpoint

First of all : I already checked all the related answers and questions .... they didn't help me

so I am trying to create ajax based like button with multiple users and multiple objects or posts i tried a lot but none of them works but i steel have the base

models.py:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    #some fields

class Like (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Like
def PostLikeToggle(request):
    #here i want to capture the request check if the user liked the post or
    # no by sending user.username and post.title to the endpoint like.html
    #and then update his status
    return render(request, 'like.html')
```

urls.py

```
from plateform import views as plateform
urlpatterns = [
    #other urls
    url(r'^like/', plateform.PostLikeToggle,  name='PostLikeToggle'),]
```

like.html

```
 {% if liked == 'false' %}
    false
  {% elif liked == 'true' %}
    true
  {% endif %}
```

blogpost.html

```
#ajax

  $('.thumb').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/like/',
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success: LikePost,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

            function LikePost(data, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
        });
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to figure it out so I added some things

models:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
        #some fields
        liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='PostLikeToggle')

    #REMOVED class Like (models.Model)
```

views:

```
def PostLikeToggle(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST['post_id']
        post = get_object_or_404(posts, id=post_id)
        _liked = user in post.liked.all()
        if _liked :
            post.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            post.liked.add(user)

    return JsonResponse({'liked':_liked})
```

So am I on the right way ??

Comment: You will need to add extra data in the request: the object you want to like.

Comment: You should post your code that isn't working so we can help you debug it, right now it looks like you just want someone else to do the full implementation for you.

Comment: You need to come up with an approach where either you soft-delete the LIKE once the post is unliked or delete the row of LIKE itself.
Also, as a hint you'll need two things to identify a LIKE uniquely - UserId and PostId

Comment: do i need to create  a foreign field into blogpost and remove the like model so if the user clicked the button i add him

Comment: please check out my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okey I will just post my answer .... it was easy trick but i was little bit stingy ...

In the models file i added ManytoMany field with the relation of users ( many users + many posts)

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    #more fields
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='PostLikeToggle')
```

in the views i created the view which it will accept the request from the blogpost views and check if user already liked the post or no ( add the user to the liked field if liked return true remove it if  .... )

```
def PostLikeToggle(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST['post_id']
        post = get_object_or_404(posts, id=post_id)
        _liked = user in post.liked.all()
        if _liked :
            post.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            post.liked.add(user)

    return JsonResponse({'liked':_liked})
```

this views is associated with url where we will get the response :

```
url(r'^like/', plateform.PostLikeToggle,  name='PostLikeToggle')
```

and in your blog post template you will need to link Jquery and add this Ajax function
(*don't forget to customize it with your own variable class , url ...* )

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: {% url 'PostLikeToggle' %},
                data: {
                    'post_id': {{ post_slug.id }},
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success: LikePost,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

            function LikePost(data, jqXHR) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data)
                if (data['liked']) {
                    $('.thumb').removeClass("fas fa-thumbs-up").addClass('far fa-thumbs-up')
                }
                else
                    {
                        $('.thumb').removeClass("far fa-thumbs-up").addClass('fas fa-thumbs-up')
                    }


            }
        });
```

this worked for this time if there is any exception or you have better way just post it and i will mark it

**NOTICE** : you have to check if the user if authenticated in the template to hide the like button or redirect him to login ....